# Http (REST) Failure with Angular5 and java vert.x

Tags: rest, angular5, vert.x

I have an Angular5 front end running via "ng serve" at localhost:4200.

My backend is a java application using vert.x and running on localhost:8080.

What I am trying to do is having the front end talk to the back end using REST.
For that I am sending a simple GET request from the frontend like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
  
  getTest() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/whiskies').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
 
}
```

My back end server looks like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("<h1>Hello from my first Vert.x 3 application</h1>");
    });

    router.get("/api/whiskies").handler(this::getAll);

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(
            config().getInteger("http.port", 8080), result -> {
                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    fut.complete();
                } else {
                    fut.fail(result.cause());
                }
            });
}

private void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .end(Json.encodePrettily(products.values()));
}
```

Now I can see in the browser console, that my GET request is sent successfully. In the browser console, I can also see, that the answer for the GET request is the desired JSON.
The back end server also logs the successful processing of the GET request.

However, in the browser console, I get an error

**Http failure response for (unknown URL): 0 Unknown Error**

Does anyone have any idea, how to fix this?

Googling already pointed me in various directions:

1. My back end server obviously does not provide an SSL certificate but
   node.js might request one.
2. It might be a problem with CORS

But I don't know how to fix those things either...

Comment: If you use chrome it could be an extension of your browser, you could try in private mode, help if you post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response you put this, to prevent CORS problems:

```
reponse.putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: Yep, that was the solution to my problem.
Thanks a lot, I was getting crazy because I couldnt figure it out...

Comment: Thanks no problem see you soon!